# Exception break triggered by "_GLOBAL__I_a" from "ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions" every time when app launch

Tags: ios, crash, breakpoints

Why do I have this following break point be triggered every time when I launch my application?
I added "All Exceptions" break point in my project, but I don't know what kind of exception is this. The app can keep running if I skip this break, however when running in the device, there's a crash happened couple times due to the same call stack.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crash is occurring during global / static initialisation. You've probably got some unsafe code tied to the initialisation of a global variable, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: Exactly, I found there are couple global ObjC instance was defined but forget to update the question. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this crash on iOS9 (beta 3), it may e related to one of the libraries you're using. If you're using Cocoapods, try to remove them one by one, until you find the responsible one.

In my case, the crash was caused by the ArcGIS SDK: https://github.com/bamse16/TestEsriiOS9